# How to persist data without using Session in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

Is there any way we can persist some data without using Session and use that at any place in any View.

The situation is , i need to display UserName at the top of my application all pages and do not want to use any State variable to keep that data.

Please suggest.

Comment: So you have some variable data, and you want to maintain its state and you don't want to use a state variable … Why not?

Comment: i m just asking if there is any other way to do same?

Comment: Without knowing what your objections are to sessions, it isn't really possible to determine what would be sufficiently different to be suitable.

Comment: no objection, just someone asked me in an interview...

Comment: Stackoverflow is for *practical, answerable problems*. This is decidedly theoretical and badly defined (and can't be better defined because its coming second-hand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm... if your user logs in and starts a Session on your server then you keep data in a State Variable anyway. If this is just a cosmetic issue, on the other hand, why not use cookies?

Comment: Either you store the data, which means storing state data on the server, or the client does which means he can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your data from the View, you can use ViewBag (MVC4) and if you want to exchange the data between the Controllers, you can use Temp.